# Filtering movies on IMDB

Tags: imdb

Is it possible to do filtering on IMDB? E.g. I would like to see a list of Thriller movies, between 1980-1985, with a score between 6-7?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this using the [advanced search](http://www.imdb.com/search/title). For example, [this search](http://www.imdb.com/search/title?genres=thriller&num_votes=5000,&production_status=released&release_date=1980,1985&title_type=feature&user_rating=6.0,7.0).